# Where is the camera component located for ACharacter?

Tags: unreal-engine4

So I just started playing around with Unreal Engine 4. I would like to learn as much as I can, so I started with a blank C++ project.

I created a new Character class for my player character, then created a Blueprint based on this class.

The character Blueprint (or some of it's components seem to have a UCameraComponent attached to it, since after making the keybindigs for movement and look up/turn I could already use my mouse to navigate the camera.

My question is, where is this UCameraComponent located? When I open the Blueprint, it seems like it doesn't have a CameraComponent in there. I also tried searching for it in the source code of ACharacter, but couldn't find anything.

[image]

I would like to adjust the camera position related to the character because right now this camera is right inside my character mesh.

Comment: There is none. The camera needs to be added manually

Comment: That's interesting. But when I hit play, there's a camera that is moving when I move the character. How is that possible?

Comment: Thats because the "Camera" is part of `AController`. The controller manages through which camera you look into the world. UE makes a dummy camera in the case there is none present that lives right into your pawn.

Comment: Oh okay, makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add it to your class manually.

In YourCharacter.h:

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Components")
USpringArmComponent* SpringArm = nullptr;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Components")
UCameraComponent* Camera = nullptr;
```

In YourCharacter.cpp constructor:

```
SpringArm = CreateDefaultSubobject<USpringArmComponent>(TEXT("Spring Arm"));
SpringArm->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);

Camera = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("Camera"));
Camera->SetupAttachment(SpringArm);
```